# How to replace Boolean value with adjecent row value from same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a Boolean value after comparing row value. I want to replace the Boolean value with the adjacent row value from the same dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
    stock_files = glob.glob("E:/Python full3files/*.csv")
    dd= pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file,header= None, prefix= 'col', usecols=[1,5,6,7])
              for file in stock_files),ignore_index= True)
    ss= dd.loc[dd.col1 =="RELIANCE",:]
    ss['Daily'] = pd.to_datetime(ss['col7']).dt.day
    ss['Daily Day'] =  ss.Daily> ss.Daily.shift(1)
    #ss['Daily Day'] = ss.where(ss['Daily']> ss['Daily'].shift(1), ss['col5'].shift(1))
    print(ss)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

df[df[Daily Day==True]]=df[Col6]

Comment: thx..."  ss['Daily Day'] =  ss.Daily> ss.Daily.shift(1)" in this code im checking if col "Daily" value greater than previous row print true if  not print false in new col "Daily Day"....what i want is "col5" value in "Daily Day" if its true an if its false then previous row value of same col "Daily Day" an not Boolean value